# Setting Up Query Elevations

Tags: solr, content-search

This is related to [Solr QueryElevationComponent component usage](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6192/solr-queryelevationcomponent-component-usage), but I'm looking for **information on getting elevation setup.**

I see some other questions involving Solr **query elevation**.

Is there documentation anywhere about getting elevation setup in the first place?

I imagine that I somehow need to get the `enableElevation`/`forceElevation` parameters into `SolrNet.Commands.Parameters.CommonQueryOptions.ExtraParams`, but I'm not sure how to get there.

I could get my own implementation of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex` in there, but unfortunately there are no override points (the obvious method, `BuildQueryOptions` is private).

We're using `Sitecore 8.2 Update-2` and `Solr 5.4.1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, trying to get `ExtraParam` to work with the `Sitecore.ContentSearch` especially in `8.*` has been unfruitful (tried getting grouping to work on groupId with no luck) as the `ExtraParams` along with a lot of other `SolrNet` pieces are locked down an unexposed through the api.  I used a *different* approach (in unrelated functionality to the grouping bit) to invoke the `suggest` handler in Solr (repurposed below):

```type-c#
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex((SitecoreIndexableItem)contextDataItem);
var serviceUrl = SolrContentSearchManager.ServiceAddress.TrimEnd('/');
var handler = "/elevate";

IEnumerable<string> results = null;
var solrUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", serviceUrl, index.Name);
var solrConnection = new SolrConnection(solrUrl);

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("q", searchTerm);
parameters.Add("enableElevation", "true");
parameters.Add("forceElevation", "true");
parameters.Add("df", "text");
parameters.Add("wt", "xml");

var xmlResponse = solrConnection.Get(handler, parameters);
var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlResponse);
//parse the returned xml into proper results
results = _parseSuggestion(xmlDocument, suggestionType).ToList();

return results;
```

Which would invoke something like `http://localhost:8983/solr/your_products_master/elevate?q=ipod&df=text&debugQuery=true&enableElevation=true&forceElevation=true`

I realize that this approach pretty much circumvents using `Predicate Builder` or really any of the `ContentSearch` api already in place. In Sitecore 9 I believe they opened up a lot of the api to allow for passing `QueryOptions` and possibly `ExtraParams` as well (have not had a chance to confirm). Hopefully this helps even if only a little.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd definitely like to avoid bypassing the ContentSearch/Linq APIs entirely, but it is a worthwhile thought.

Comment: Yep, totally understood. I know in my `Suggest` case I had a very finite list of results being returned. Ultimately what are you trying to do? Get a set of `Items` returned to the top as `sponsored` or `weighted` results?  Just curious if there is a different solution to the feature ask in particular.

Comment: The use case is that there are some conditions based on the text query that should cause certain results to appear at the top. For instance, if the query is the name of a brand, the brand landing page should appear first. This would be easy to do by reordering the result list after query time, but this isn't feasible when doing paginated results. For functionality purposes, I could construct a query to generate a stupidly high boost value for those, but that screws with the scoring in a way that I don't like.

Comment: Make sense, boost/scoring is what I was wondering.  My other thought, since you likely know which items are a `Brand Landing Page` if ordering results by `TemplateID/Name` or using some computed bool field (ie: `TopResults`) to order by to get those `Landing Pages` to render higher?

Comment: Changing the ordering at query time would prevent the default ordering by score, which is something I need. And doing a computed field wouldn't help, as whether the landing page should be at the top is dependent on the text query the user types in.